# SSRS does not return all rows the stored procedure does

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, optional-parameters

I created a complex SSRS report and a stored procedure that has multiple parameters for a Sales Order Number, Customer PO, Order Status, Purchase Order Number, and then a selection on customer and vendor.

When running the report for a few specific Sales Order Numbers all rows are not returned or no rows at all. When I run the stored procedure for those same Sales Order Numbers, all rows are shown as expected.

The only way I can show the correct data in SSRS is by using the parameter selection for the Vendor.

The parameters look as follows:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMasterPipelineReport] 
    @SalesOrderNumber AS varchar(21),
    @CustomerPO AS varchar(21), 
    @Selection AS varchar(250), 
    @PurchaseOrderNumber AS varchar(21), 
    @Vendor AS varchar(MAX),  
    @Customer AS varchar(MAX)
```

The where clause in the query:

```
WHERE  
    (@SalesOrderNumber IS NULL OR SalesOrderNumber = @SalesOrderNumber)
    AND (@CustomerPO IS NULL OR CSTPONBR = @CustomerPO) 
    AND  Selection IN (SELECT * FROM dba_parseString_udf(@Selection, ',')) 
    AND (@PurchaseOrderNumber IS NULL OR PONUMBER = @PurchaseOrderNumber) 
    AND POVENDORID IN (SELECT * FROM dba_parseString_udf(@Vendor, ','))
    AND CUSTNMBR IN (SELECT * FROM dba_parseString_udf(@Customer, ','))
```

In SSRS the parameter for Sales Order Number is set to:

```
=IIF(Parameters!SalesOrderNumber.Value ="",Nothing,Parameters!SalesOrderNumber.Value)
```

I can't seem to identify what needs to be changed order to show ALL relevant rows.

Comment: Are you running in visual studio? If so, make sure you are nit running a cached version of the data. SSRS projects cache data into report.data files. The real data is only refreshed when a parameter changes or the green refresh error is clicked. Make sure this is not your issue.

Comment: If in VS, you can also manually delete the cached data by deleted the `.rdl.data` file for the report, which is in the project folder. Make sure you do this when you aren't previewing the report.

Comment: Are you sure Nothing in SSRS passes a NULL to the database and not an empty string? You could always "NULL out" empty string parameters in the SP, before the query, like this: `IF @SalesOrderNumber = '' SET @SalesOrderNumber = NULL`

Comment: Maybe I misread but are you saying your `SalesOrderNumber` parameter is multi-valued and it won't return all of the rows when you enter multiple order numbers?  You may need to use the same `parseString` function on that parameter in the `where` clause, as well.

Comment: @RossBush I'm not in Visual Studio but might be able to open the project up in VS if that is necessary.

Comment: @HardCode I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Steve_o169 SalesOrderNumber is not multi-valued it is either entered as a parameter one Sales Order Number or not entered at all.

Comment: First thing I would do is run the SQL Profiler, then run the SP then the report with the same parameters. Check the profiler output to see what is actually getting executed in each instance and that should point you to the issue. I would guess parameters values are not being passed quite as you expect.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I'll work on this today and report back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.  Debugging the stored procedure lead me to find that there were trailing spaces in the actual values output by the stored procedure which were not passed to the report parameter at run-time in SSRS.  In the stored procedure, I added RTRIM to the columns where additional spaces were used to filter the results.  After doing so, the report rendered with the correct data in SSRS.